# Scripto to update Sharepoint Online content type

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-online

I have a content type "TestContentType" with three columns:

- Document Type
- Category
- Sub-category

This content type is used on 18 document libraries, in 3 site collections.

The Category column needs to have a "description" added which currently has no description. Is there a  way to achieve this via a script so I don't have to make change manually via the UI.

So far I have come up with the following script, but this so far only lists all list and document libraries. What I actually need is to be able to get the content type in this  case "TestContentType" and then update the "Category" column to include a description:

```
$loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$webUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "HTTPS URL for the SP Online 2013 site" 
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Email address login"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Password for $username" -AsSecureString


$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
$web = $ctx.Web
$lists = $web.Lists
$ctx.Load($lists)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$lists| select -Property Title
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to update site column used in Content Type, [Field.UpdateAndPushChanges method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.updateandpushchanges.Aspx)  could be utilized. It commits changed properties of the field and propagates changes to all lists that use the field.

The following example demonstrates how to update field `Description` and propagate this change to all lists:

```
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securedPassword)

$field = $ctx.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldTitle)
$field.Description = $fieldDesc
$field.UpdateAndPushChanges($True)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

> Note: The specified script have to be executed per every site
>   collection.

Comment: Great thanks for this Vadim. I will do a quick test on dev tenant, but hopefully this should do it.

Comment: Do I have to do this for every field that I add to the content type?

Comment: What if I've added a field to the content type *after* using the content type in a list?  This means the list doesn't already have that column in it.  Will this push that column to the list?